# Debug VUE app for REST API call protected using Auth0 in VS Code

Tags: vue.js, auth0, restful-authentication, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug Auth0 [code](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/02-calling-an-api) for a VUE app calling a REST API endpoint protected by Auth0.
In VS Code I have a weird behavior during debugging.

Consider the following code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-5">
      <h1>External API</h1>
      <p>
        Call an external API by clicking the button below. This will call the
        external API using an access token, and the API will validate it using
        the API's audience value.
      </p>

      <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5" @click="callApi">Call API</button>
    </div>

    <div class="result-block-container">
      <div :class="['result-block', executed ? 'show' : '']">
        <h6 class="muted">Result</h6>
        <pre v-highlightjs="JSON.stringify(apiMessage, null, 2)">
          <code class="js rounded"></code>
        </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Api",
  data() {
    return {
      apiMessage: null,
      executed: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async callApi2() {
      this.executed = true;
      try {
        const { data } = await this.$http.get(
          "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/posts"
        );

        this.apiMessage = data;
        //throw new Error("New sync error");
      } catch (error) {
        this.apiMessage = error.stack;
      }
    },

    async callApi() {
      this.executed = true;
      try {
        const accessToken = await this.$auth.getTokenSilently();
        const { data } = await this.$http.get("/api/external", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        });

        this.apiMessage = data;
      } catch (error) {
        //console.log(err);
        this.apiMessage = `Error: the server responded with '${error.response.status}: ${error.response.statusText}'`;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Methods `callApi2` and `callApi` are almost the same but If I try to debug the second method by placing a breakpoint  at `catch` I'm not able to see `error` content. I can debug the first method without any issue even in presence of an error (explicitly generated or not).

File "launch.json" is as follow:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "pathMapping": {
        "/_karma_webpack_": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "serve"
    }
  ]
}
```

File "tasks.json" is:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "serve",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "serve-vue",
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": [
        {
          "base": "$tsc-watch",
          "background": {
            "activeOnStart": true,
            "beginsPattern": "Starting development server",
            "endsPattern": "Compiled successfully"
          }
        }
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't figure it out why.

Answer (score 0):

By further investigation of the above issue, I notice that using Promise syntax instead of async/await the VS Code debugger seems to work fine (I can inspect error in the debugger).
I suppose is a problem of settings reported in launch.json, but I can't figure it out why/what.
Below the revised code:

```
methods: {
    // this method has debug issues
    async callApi2() {
      this.executed = true;
      try {
        const { data } = await this.$http.get(
          "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/posts5"
        );
        this.apiMessage = data;
      } catch (error) {
        this.apiMessage = error.stack;
      }
    },
    // this method without async/await has no debugging issues !!
    callApi() {
      this.executed = true;

      const accessToken = "gjkgkjgk"; //await this.$auth.getTokenSilently();
      this.$http
        .get("/api/external", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        })
        .then((data) => (this.apiMessage = data))
        .catch(
          (error) =>
            //console.log(err);
            (this.apiMessage = `Error: the server responded with '${error.response.status}: ${error.response.statusText}'`)
        );
    },
  },
};
</script>
```